# Short Description lost through Mage::register

Tags: product, magento-1, product-attribute, data

So I am trying to get a reference to the current product in my Block with

```
$product = Mage::registry("current_product");
```

Which seems to work fine, but the `$product->getShortDescription` is returning null.

I tried debugging this myself by stepping through the product helper `initProduct` method and upon inspecting the Product Model, the data is as expected. i.e:

```
_data["short_description"] = "SOME SHORT DESCRIPTION"
```

After registering the product

```
# app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php
344| // Register current data and dispatch final events
345| Mage::register('current_product', $product);
346| Mage::register('product', $product);
```

the short description seem to be lost.

```
_data["short_description"] = null
```

Has anyone else had this issue? It would be cool to know how to solve it.

**NOTE**: It could have something to do with the Model rewriting that happens with the registry...

Thanks guys.

Comment: The purpose of his question was to find how to get the data from the registry, WITHOUT having to make another database request, as the loaded model is saved to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the attribute direct in the product page you have to enable it first from  backend.
go to admin->catalog->manage attribute and find for short description.

when you click it you will find "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" make it yes . i hope this will work for you.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, should have said I ensured it is `Visible on Product View Page on Frontend`

Answer (score 0):

You have to load product after that you will get short description

```
$productId = Mage::registry("current_product")->getId();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getShortDescription();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so quickly. This definitely would work, it's just to my understanding, when we register a model through the registry, it is a 'state' of that model, meaning if the model is saved after loading, I thought it would be loaded when getting it from the registry again.

I have a sneaking suspicion there's a bug in the registering of models.

I was hoping I could avoid having to 're'-load the product after getting it from the registry.

Comment: You have tried with `$product->getShortDescription()` bracket in end of description?

Comment: oh, most definitely. I think there might be a core issue with textarea values being saved in the registry. It seems to work fine if my short description doesn't have line separators in them.

I know a little bit more about coding than to look for a property when I meant a function. Didn't think it would matter as I was explaining a process rather than detailing the actual code I wrote :)

So in short, yes I ran the function `$this->getShortDescription()`